# Bootloader can't detect Deepin OS

Tags: linux, windows-7, grub, grub2, dualboot

I installed Deepin OS using Deepin boot maker and it installed successfully. After installation there was Reboot Now option. I pressed on this but bootloader didn't detect Deepin OS. But I could boot to Windows 7. Is there any way to add it manually? Can I do it using EasyBCD? And if I can then which loader must I choose? Grub or Grub2? Syslinux? Other?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by myself. First you must install EasyBCD. After installation launch program. You will see add boot entry option at the left. Press on that and at the right top you will see Linux. Go to that panel and select Grub2 from 1 raw then choose name for that boot entry and at the last select the drive that you installed Deepin OS. Done!
Reboot your pc and select Deepin from bootloader.